# Unexpected indent in multicolumn of a tabular table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

When I use multicolumn in a tabular table, the text is always indented compared to the other rows where no multicolumn is defined.

How can I solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}                           % define a multicols environment which typesets text in multiple columns
\usepackage{colortbl}                           % background color for row, columns or individual cells in a table
\usepackage{xcolor}                             % foreground (text, rules, etc.) and background colour management

\definecolor{beige}{cmyk}{0.16,0.03,0.31,0}
\definecolor{shamrock}{cmyk}{0.71,0.29,1,0.13}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}    % define a new column type for a fixed-width right-aligned column - middle vertical alignment
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}   % define a new column type for a fixed-width left-aligned column - middle vertical alignment

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L{110mm} R{35mm}} 
    \cellcolor{beige}
    \textbf{Column title} 
    & \cellcolor{beige}
    \textbf{99.999,99 EUR} \\
    \multicolumn{2}{L{145mm}}{
        \color{shamrock}I don't understand why this text is left indented. The other text
        is not indented in the table. I don't understand why this text is left indented. The other text
        is not indented in the table.
    } \\
    \color{shamrock}Title: 
    & \color{shamrock}99.999,99 EUR \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `m` column type isn't factoring in the inter-column separation of the two columns, so your specified `\multicolumn` width is shorter than the actual width of the table. For reasons that aren't entirely clear to me, `\multicolumn` then aligns the text so that the right edge is flush with the end of the second column. Note that `p` and `b` don't behave this way. The effect is very obvious if you reduce the `\multicolumn` width even more. (Try reducing the width to 100mm to see what I mean.)

The easiest way to fix it is to eliminate the inter-column spacing between the two ordinary columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{L{110mm}@{}R{35mm}} 
  \textbf{Column title}  & \textbf{99.999,99 EUR} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{L{145mm}}{
      CI don't understand why this text is left indented. The other text 
        is not indented in the table. I don't understand why this text is left indented. The other text
        is not indented in the table.
    } \\
  Title: & 99.999,99 EUR \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The size of the `\multicolumn` doesn't take into account the two `\tabcolsep` between the columns.

In the example below I use `m`, so the center multicolumn cell is justified.

Note that `multicol` has no bearing with this example; instead of loading first `colortbl` and then `xcolor`, it's better to load just the latter with the `table` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{beige}{cmyk}{0.16,0.03,0.31,0}
\definecolor{shamrock}{cmyk}{0.71,0.29,1,0.13}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L{110mm} R{35mm}} 
\cellcolor{beige}\textbf{Column title} & \cellcolor{beige}\textbf{99.999,99 EUR} \\
\multicolumn{2}{m{\dimexpr145mm+2\tabcolsep}}{%
  \color{shamrock}I don't understand why this text is left indented. The other text
  is not indented in the table. I don't understand why this text is left indented.
  The other text is not indented in the table.
} \\
\color{shamrock}Title: & \color{shamrock}99.999,99 EUR \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]